# PyBugz version when installing Gitzilla

Tags: git, bugzilla, pybugz

I'm trying to install Gitzilla, and I'm running into the 'no module named Bugz' problem mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gitzilla-talk/zbM4AH6g1ts%5B1-25%5D).

Anyone knows where to take the 0.9.3 PyBugz version metioned in the link above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu:

- Download PyBugs: `git clone https://github.com/williamh/pybugz.git` and cd to the new pybugz directory
- Verify tag 0.9.3 exists: `git tag`
- Checkout the 0.9.3 tag: `git checkout 0.9.3`
- Install the library: `sudo python setup.py install`